# Why does SciPy require an installation procedure?

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to wrap my head around the Python ecosystem and parts of it aren't making complete sense to me so far.

I'm coming from the Java world and when I want to make use of, say JUnit, I simply add the JUnit jar to my classpath and that's pretty much it. If I want to be nice to my users I can also easily bunch together all my dependencies into a single jar, so that all that they need to do is install a Java Runtime get a hold of my jar.

Reading through the SciPy installation guide I can't find an explanation for why all this is really necessary. And how is this ever going to work at deployment time? It's like JUnit asked me to install a new JRE just for them.

Answer (score 3):

SciPy has parts written in C that require compilation for the specific platform it's being deployed too.

> ## How can SciPy be fast if it is written in an interpreted language like Python?
>
> Actually, the time-critical loops are usually implemented in C or
>   Fortran. Much of SciPy is a thin layer of code on top of the
>   scientific routines that are freely available at
>   http://www.netlib.org/. Netlib is a huge repository of incredibly
>   valuable and robust scientific algorithms written in C and Fortran. It
>   would be silly to rewrite these algorithms and would take years to
>   debug them. SciPy uses a variety of methods to generate “wrappers”
>   around these algorithms so that they can be used in Python. Some
>   wrappers were generated by hand coding them in C. The rest were
>   generated using either SWIG or f2py. Some of the newer contributions
>   to SciPy are either written entirely or wrapped with Cython.

Source:  http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/faq.html#id12

> On Linux, SciPy and NumPy libraries’ official releases are source-code
>   only. Installing NumPy and SciPy from source is reasonably easy;
>   However, both packages depend on other software, some of them which
>   can be challenging to install, or shipped with incompatibilities by
>   major Linux distributions. Hopefully, you can install NumPy and SciPy
>   without any software outside the necessary tools to build python
>   extensions, as most dependencies are optional

Source:  http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/building/linux.html

Comment: So in between Cygwin, Anaconda, and the standard version I now have 3 different Python interpreters running around on my system. Is this the way its supposed to be? And when the next library with C code draws my fancy I'll gradually be adding Python interpreter 4, 5, and 6?

Comment: There are schools of thought on how to best organise a system for python development or deployment.  I'm not a SciPy user so I don't really have a horse in this race.  For a pretty passionate opinion on how Python environments should be handled, you could take a look at this and the discussions sparked by it:  https://pythonrants.wordpress.com/2013/12/06/why-i-hate-virtualenv-and-pip/

Comment: No. You can always build scipy from source for your chosen interpreter yourself (easy on *nix, harder on OS X, still harder on Windows). Or get precompiled binaries (not just Anaconda, also eg Gohlke binaries on Windows).